# The system was extended by/with several new functions

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

I would like to know whether the following is correct:

> The system was extended by several new functions.
>
> Our tool extends the system by a few new functions.

I have read similar questions but could not find a clear reasoning as for when should I choose which.

Comment: We usually use ***by*** when we're talking *literally* about the additional amount (of length, area, or time), and ***with*** to refer to the *method or material* involved in the extension. So *A snooker cue can be extended **by** 30cm **with** a special extra handle* (usually called *a cue extension* anyway, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot, that is very helpful, why not make it an answer?